# Testfor an item in player's hand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I test for a player with scoreboard holding a skull with damage 2s in his active slot with a name? I tried SelectedItem instead of Inventory, but it didn't work. I do it in 1.9. 
Here is a command:

```
/testfor @a[score_Medusashead_min=1,score_Medusashead=1] {SelectedItem:[{id:minecraft:skull,Damage:2s,tag:{display:{Name:"Medusa's head"}}Count:1b}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `SelectedItem`'s value is an object, not an array. That means that you should remove the square brackets around the `SelectedItem` tag's value. The next thing to do is to add a comma before `Count:1b`. Your final command should then be:

```
/testfor @a[score_Medusashead_min=1,score_Medusashead=1] {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:skull,Damage:2s,tag:{display:{Name:"Medusa's head"}},Count:1b}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the SelectedItemSlot thing, so it is now solved. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, no problem.